# Unable to generate signed apk with react native

Tags: react-native

By following command mentioned on documentation, I'm trying to generate signed apk for android and getting following error

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in D:\ReactNativeProj\App\node_modules (23ms
) Building 88% > :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: D:\ReactNativeProj\App\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Copying 22 asset files
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done copying assets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)
```

Following this link for generate production apk

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

after generate build through below command apk generated successfully

```
gradlew assembleRelease --console plain
```

but after install apk getting crash on startup with following error.

```
11-23 15:36:25.532  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
11-23 15:36:25.542  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
11-23 15:36:25.542  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
11-23 15:36:25.543  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
11-23 15:36:25.543  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
11-23 15:36:25.543  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
11-23 15:36:25.677  7135  7157 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
11-23 15:36:25.994  7135  7157 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
11-23 15:36:26.003  7135  7157 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
11-23 15:36:26.022  7135  7157 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
11-23 15:36:26.022  7135  7157 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
11-23 15:36:26.045  7135  7180 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
11-23 15:36:26.045  7135  7180 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
11-23 15:36:27.113  7135  7179 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.View.propTypes.style')
11-23 15:36:25.532  7135  7135 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands:

```
yourCurrentProjectDirectory> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

then:

```
cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Now your signed APK is built; you can deploy on any android device

```
adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
```

Comment: I tried all these commands, now error changed. I have updated question with new error.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

finally build:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```